# Using implicit differentiation to find the angle between two tangents to a circle from a point

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm working on the following problem and would appreciated any input from you.

> Two tangent lines are drawn from the point $P(-2(1+\sqrt{3}), 2(1+\sqrt{3}))$ to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, touching the circle at the points $Q$ and $R$. Find the exact value of the $\angle QRP$.

A diagram, while not drawn to scale, is provided below as a hint.

[image]

Comment: I know it is just a sketch, but the way it is drawn, it is plausible that Q is a point of tangency, but R, not so much.

Comment: @mjw Thanks for the comment. What makes you say that?

Comment: Again, it is a sketch, but extend the line from P to R.  It goes into the interior of the circle.  The diagram is okay.  Sorry for the criticism ...

Comment: Must we use implicit differentiation to solve this problem? It seems like it would be simpler to just treat it geometrically.

Comment: @Infiaria, How would you suggest accomplishing that?

Comment: @mjw, Ah, I see! Good catch. I didn't personally make the diagram, so your criticism is well received.

Comment: @Optimizationally Let $O(0,0)$. Use [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales's_theorem) to realise that the angle $\angle PQO$ is $90^\circ$. You know the radius is 2, and the distance of $OP$ using Pythagoras, so you can work out $\angle QPO$ using basic trigonometry. Then double it for the angle between the two tangents.

Comment: @Infiaria, Finding the distance between OP is precisely my problem. The intuition behind this is unclear to me. It's possible I've been looking at this problem a bit too long.

Comment: @Optimizationally Pythagoras' theorem, $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$? The point $(-2(1+\sqrt{3}), 2(1+\sqrt{3}))$ goes $2(1+\sqrt{3})$ to the left and $2(1+\sqrt{3})$ upwards!

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them: algebraic-geometry explicitly says it is not for elementary problems involving both geometry and algebra, such as this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Name the center of the circle $O$. Then$$PO=2\sqrt 2(1+\sqrt 3)\\OQ=2$$also $\angle PQO=90$ therefore$$\angle QPO=\sin ^{-1}{QO\over PO}\\\angle QPR=2\angle QPO\\\angle QRP=90-{\angle QPR\over 2}$$

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: Thank you so much! Yours is too interesting following a different attitude...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, Thanks for the hint! How did you come to the length of $PO=2\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Your welcome. It is actually the Euclidean distance between $P(-2(1+\sqrt 3),2(1+\sqrt 3))$ and $O(0,0)$ using the following formula$$\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=(-a,a)$ where $a=2(1+\sqrt{3}).$

At point $Q=(x_0,y_0)$, the vector $(x_0+a,y_0-a)^T$ is perpendicular to the vector $(x_0,y_0)$ leading to $x_0^2+y_0^2 + a(x_0-y_0)=0 \Rightarrow a(y_0-x_0)=4.$  Thus $y_0=x_0+ \frac{4}{a}$.  Substituting into the equation for the circle, we get $x_0=2-\frac{4}{a}$ and $y_0=2$ (taking the positive solution to the quadratic equation).

So $Q=(2-\frac{4}{a}, 2)$.  By symmetry, $R=(-y_0, -x_0) = (-2,\frac{4}{a}-2)$.  Recall $P=(-a,a)$.  We now have the three vertices of the triangle.  We can compute the value of any angle of this triangle with $\displaystyle\cos \alpha = \frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|}$.  For example, if $\alpha$ is $\angle QRP$, $\mathbf{u}=(x_0+y_0,x_0+y_0)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (y_0-a,a-x_0)$.